# cellular automata to simulate 2d clouds

Tags: algorithm, cellular-automata

I've recently stepped into cellular automata and I've been looking everywhere for an automata that can simulate clouds' behaviour. I don't want it to be perfect, just to be a random and infinite algorithm that looks like clouds (e.g. when they gather or separate, just like the image below).[image]

This image is not an illustration of an algorithm, it's just an example of the behaviour I'm looking for.

My question is: **Is there any algorithm that approximates this behaviour or somewhere to look for it?** I searched a lot and didn't find anything. I've looked for Game of Life similars, as well as epidemic algorithms.

Comment: Interesting topic. But probably too broad for this site.

Comment: I'm sorry, I know it is kind of an abstract question, but I had nowhere else to ask, I've been throught a lot of scientific papers and articles but still haven't found what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Might be unrelevant to the prime poster after such a long time, but for the others it seems close to the metaball algorithm.